# How many amps in the pictured breaker?

Tags: circuit-breaker

This 220 volt circuit has two 30amp breakers. Does that make it an 60 amp circuit?[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, it's a 30A circuit at 240V on the USA/Canada system where two hots are each 120V from neutral but they are 240V from each other. That is a [single two-pole breaker](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/HOM230/mini-circuit-breaker-homeline-30a-2-pole-120-240vac-10ka-air-standard-type-plug-in-ul/?%3Frange=7228-square-d-homeline-miniature-circuit-breakers&selectedNodeId=48911549517), not two breakers.

*220V went out of vogue here about the Eisenhower presidency...*

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is the amount of power, which is measured in Watts.

A 30A double breaker can handle 30A x 240V (nominal, but in some buildings it will be 208V nominal) = 7,200W. The actual load for a water heater is limited by code to 80% of that = 30A x 240V x 0.8 = 5,760W. And a *typical* water heater is designed to use either 4,500W or 5,500W.

There aren't too many 30A 120V circuits in common residential use. One somewhat common usage is for certain types of RVs. Hypothetically, you could connect two 30A 120V circuits to this same double-breaker and each one would get 30A x 120V = 3,600W, and in fact you would then have a total of **60A** x 120V available, but the same 7,200W of power as 30A x 240V.

There are 60A 240V circuits, typically used for subpanel feeds but occasionally for other things like wildly oversized EVSE ("car charging"), which would provide 14,400W peak and 11,520W continuous. I am not aware of any 60A 120V circuits in common use in the US.

But one very important thing to keep in mind is that breakers and wires must match:

- voltage is based on the *type* of wire, particularly the insulation - for practical purposes in US residential usage this is not a big deal as most wire is rated at 600V and even 300V is enough for 120V or 240V circuits
- current is based on the *size* of wire. There are a lot of variables involved and [charts are available](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) to tell you what works. But a wire for 30A (same for 120V or 240V) will be much smaller and cheaper than a wire for 60A.

Putting all of that together, the result is that to get a particular power level (e.g., to heat water or dry clothes or charge your car) requires less current and therefore smaller wire if you use higher voltage than if you use lower voltage. The only practical options in the US for most homes is 120V ("single breakers") or 240V ("double breakers", like in the picture) which is why water heaters, clothes dryers, ovens, EV chargers and other devices that use a lot of *power* use double breakers.